# Recursive function for finding available indexes returning 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, recursion

Essentially I have key-value pairs being made into inputs on a form.

Initially, I was just defining them as `inputname['key']`, with the value attached.

I realized that there's a third parameter that is required to be encoded, as items in the array with the same key would overwrite other inputs with different values.

I wrote a very simplistic (or so I thought) recursive function to tell if a given index is available or not. It is below

```
addString: function(str) {
    var maxInd = this.checkCurrentReturnIndex(str, 0);
    return 'friends['+maxInd+str+']';
},
checkCurrentReturnIndex(userid, currentInd) {
   // Recursive function to determine proper, unused index
   if(!$('input[name="friends['+currentInd+userid+'"]').length) {
       return currentInd;
   } else {
       return this.checkCurrentReturnIndex(userid, (currentInd + 1));
   }
},
```

This is inside Vue methods, and despite a few different variations on the code above, I can't get it to output anything that isn't 0.

Comment: that suggests `$('input[name="friends['+currentInd+userid+'"]').length` is always 0 - without any hint of your web page, the issue is that there is no input that has an attribute like `name="friends[0xxx]"` where xxx is whatever `userid` is

Comment: by the way, whenever I see vue.js and jquery used together, I think *you're doing it wrong* - but that's not just my opinion

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context what you're trying to accomplish. I would say initially your likely conflating your presentation and data layers, or at least should be generating more separation here.  Might have an easier way to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might just be constructing your jQuery selector incorrectly.

Based on your code sample, I'm assuming your HTML looks something like this, where the `userid`s are `user01`, `user02`, etc., prefixed by unique indexes for that user:

```html
<input type="text" name="friends[0user01]">
<input type="text" name="friends[1user01]">
<input type="text" name="friends[2user01]">
<input type="text" name="friends[0user02]">
<input type="text" name="friends[1user02]">
<input type="text" name="friends[2user02]">
<input type="text" name="friends[3user02]">
```

Your selector currently looks like this:

```js
$('input[name="friends['+currentInd+userid+'"]')
//                        closing " is here ^
```

which, for a `currentInd` of `0` and a `userid` of `user01`, would become this:

```js
$('input[name="friends[0user01"]');
//          closing " is here ^
```

which I suspect is not correct.

If you move the closing `"` outside of the closing bracket like so:

```js
$('input[name="friends['+currentInd+userid+']"')
//                              move to here ^
```

the selector will look like this:

```js
$('input[name="friends[0user01]"')
//           closing " is here ^
```

Which might solve your problem.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikejacobson/bta5jw10/10/) that seems to be working with just that small correction—your recursive function was built correctly.